# Share access to HTTP server on OSX?

Tags: macos, networking, dns, proxy

I recently became aware of http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/share/, which enables:

> HTTP sharing will create a URL that you can give to anyone. This URL
>   will route directly into your Vagrant environment.

For those who are not familiar, Vagrant is a configuration abstraction on top of virtualisation software (VirtualBox, VMware, etc).

I would love to be able to do this on the OSX. I already have a running web server on port `:8000` and I would like a service that would enable sharing access to this port through some sort of proxy/dynamic DNS service.

The prerequisites are:

- I should not need to have a static IP.
- I should not need to have a port mapping to my machine from the outside net.

What are the existing software/configuration/service solutions?

Comment: Try OS X Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is dedicated for those who start with the same keywords.

It turns out, I needed a reverse SSH tunnel. There are quite a few guides as to how to set it up:

- https://www.calazan.com/how-to-share-your-local-web-server-to-the-internet-using-a-reverse-ssh-tunnel/
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/11/reverse-ssh-tunnel/
- https://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling
- https://serverfault.com/questions/361794/reverse-proxy-web-access-on-a-server-where-only-ssh-is-allowed

The prerequisite is that you will need to have a remote server to use as the entry point. As an alternative, there are a number of services that do that for you:

- http://localtunnel.me/
- https://ngrok.com/
- https://forwardhq.com/

and a lot more http://john-sheehan.com/blog/a-survey-of-the-localhost-proxying-landscape.